# Вычесть значения первого многомерного массива от значений второго многомерного массива

Tags: php, php7

Первый массив.

```
array(
    array(
        'position' => 125632,
        'balance' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 112332,
        'balance' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 124442,
        'balance' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 545632,
        'balance' => 8
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 629652,
        'balance' => 2
    ),
)
```

Второй массив

```
array(
    array(
        'position' => 125632,
        'positionQuantity' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 112332,
        'positionQuantity' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 124442,
        'positionQuantity' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 545632,
        'positionQuantity' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 629652,
        'positionQuantity' => 1
    ),
)
```

Результат который нужно получить.

```
array(
    array(
        'position' => 125632,
        'balance' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 112332,
        'balance' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 124442,
        'balance' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 545632,
        'balance' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'position' => 629652,
        'balance' => 1
    ),
)
```

Я решил данный вопрос следующим методом. Но возможно есть метод более лаконичный.

```
$newArray1 = array_column($array1, 'position', 'balance');
$newArray2 = array_column($array2, 'positionQuantity', 'position');
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    $returPositions[] = array(
        'position' => $value['position'],
        'balance' => $value['balance'] - $newArray2[$value['position']],
    );
};
```

Comment: Сперва вы должны попробовать самостоятельно решить задачу, а в случае неудачи - опубликовать результат ваших попыток.

Comment: Добавил свое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Если вычитать надо элементы одинаковыми индексами, то как то так

```
$result = array_map(function($a,$b ){
                $a['balance'] -= $b['positionQuantity'];
                return $a;
            }, $arr1, $arr2);
```